# Getting the radiobox state between postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

```
I have got this code:

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public bool  MyProperty { get; set; }
    Button newBTN;
    GenerateMe gm;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        newBTN = new Button();
        newBTN.Text = "Button 1";


        gm = new GenerateMe(PlaceHolder1, newBTN);
        gm.ExecuteAll();       
        Response.Write(gm.ResponseWrite());

    }


}

class GenerateMe
{
    PlaceHolder holder;
    Button button;
    RadioButton b = new RadioButton();
    string buttonPressed;

    public GenerateMe(PlaceHolder h, Button b)
    {
        holder = h;
        button = b;
    }

    public void ExecuteAll()
    {

        Table t = new Table();
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Controls.Add(button);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        t.Rows.Add(tr);
        holder.Controls.Add(t);
        holder.Controls.Add(b);
        if (b.Checked)//This is always false
        {
            buttonPressed = b.Checked.ToString();
        }

    }

    public string ResponseWrite()
    {
        return buttonPressed;
    }

}
```

I can see that the radiobox is checked..But its checked property is false all the time between post backs. How do i get the radiobox state if it was pressed..

ps. I dont want to use the radioboxes events.. I want to get a property if it was pressed after a postback

Comment: Where is the CheckBox in the code?  are you talking about the radio button?

Comment: Sorry it is a radio box..i used checkbox before..i changed it

Comment: At which point you are checking the radio button's status? specify that in the code as a comment or something.

Comment: I clearly specified in the code!

Comment: Then it seems a big logical problem. cuz at the point you are doing it the b variable is always a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the variable in session variable.

```
Session["buttonPressed"]="checked";
```

in other page call it as:

```
string check=Session["buttonPressed"].ToString();
```

EDIT:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {   

        newBTN = new Button();
        newBTN.Text = "Button 1";


        gm = new GenerateMe(PlaceHolder1, newBTN);
        gm.ExecuteAll();       
        Response.Write(gm.ResponseWrite());
       }
    }
```

Use PreInit event to generate the controls.

Comment: @Dmitry You want to fetch it in a different page right? 
ViewState is pretty good for storing simple values for use in the form, but if you wish to save more complex data, and keep them from page to page, you should look into using cookies or sessions.[Refer this article.](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/viewstate/)

Comment: the b.Checked.ToString is always false!.. Thats cause of the postback.. when i click the button, a postback happen.. But before it happens i cant fetch  whether it was checked or not... But it the checkbox does seem to be checked after the postback (actually it is a radio box..sorry)..

Comment: Whats so complex about bool :(

Comment: @Dmitry Since you are instantiating the radio button in a class and checking its state there itself, so it will always return false, irrespective of user action. The question is a difficult to understand with the user design. Can you show the aspx file?

Comment: The aspx file has got only a placeholder on it!

Comment: @Dmitry Keep the Page Load Code under if(!Page.IsPostBack). Check edited answer!

Comment: If that is the case then use the PreInit event to generate the controls.

Comment: @Dmitry "The aspx file has got only a placeholder on it!" <-- Why aren't you creating the controls in the aspx file as markup?